# jQuery autocomplete with google map address lookup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, google-maps-api-3, jquery-autocomplete

How I can reproduce [this plugin](http://gmap3.net/examples/address-lookup.html) in jsfiddle ? Code so far is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VBFxp/2/).
My problem is- I can see response data is coming for each request using firebug, but the autocomplete list is not showing up. Thanks for your time guys.

Adding the code directly from fiddle -
HTML :

```
<!-- required js libraries -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> <!-- jQuery is directly loaded from fiddle, so in the live example I skipped this line -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gmap3.net/js/gmap3-4.1-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/jbdemonte/autocomplete/master/jquery-autocomplete.min.js"></script>

<!-- this is required to help autocomplete plugin -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://raw.github.com/jbdemonte/autocomplete/master/jquery-autocomplete.css" />

<input type="text" id="address" size="60"/>
<div id="test" style="height:350px; width:600px"></div>​
```

And here is the javascript :

```
/*This one initializes the map*/
$("#test").gmap3();

/*This is the autocomplete code*/
$('#address').autocomplete({
  source: function() {
    $("#test").gmap3({
      action:'getAddress',
      address: $(this).val(),
      callback:function(results){
        if (!results) return;
        $('#address').autocomplete(
          'display', 
          results,
          false
        );
      }
    });
  },
  cb:{
    cast: function(item){
      return item.formatted_address;
    },
    select: function(item) {
      $("#test").gmap3(
        {action:'clear', name:'marker'},
        {action:'addMarker',
          latLng:item.geometry.location,
          map:{center:true}
        }
      );
    }
  }
});​
```

Comment: Not sure what happened. Tried but failed. Btw do you know GMapsv3 has autocomplete built in? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Autocomplete

Comment: no problem. The autocomplete provided by GMaps is deadly simple and no additional library needed. Checkout their example on this page: http://code.google.com/p/geo-autocomplete/

Comment: @LionelChan , that simply awesome ! just checked and compared with mine, the built-in GMap API is giving nearer and more number of suggestions. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can make your version work by wrapping the input in a container and adding some margin between that container and map. I don't think the css is being delivered properly from github resource as I also had to add some extra z-index to get the results list to show over top of map

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VBFxp/3/

Comment: missing css might be related to https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-docs-alpha/issues/95

Comment: my added margin likely not required when proper css delivered. But The container for autocomplete to append to is likely a must

Comment: @schellmax , thank you so much ! The CSS was actually not delivered. I copied and pasted the css instead of loading through the URL and it worked. Thanks everyone !